# How to stop random ordering of slides for ng-bootstrap carousel

Tags: carousel, ng-bootstrap

I have implemented ng-bootstrap carousal in my project with *ngFor loop. I have uploaded five images and the slideshow is showing all 5 images but the ordering of the slides is getting changed every time. I want to display the slides in specific order. After reading the API documentation could not find any help regarding stopping the random slide ordering behavior.

Comment: Kindly share your TS code here... that'll make it easier to help

Comment: There is no specific ts file for this. I have just installed in ng-bootstarp and applied <ngb-carousel  interval='false' data-interval='false' [pauseOnHover]='true'></ngb-carousel>, inside that *ngFor loop is running for displaying images

Comment: in the *ngFor loop, you would give the name of the array, right? where is the array? - share the HTML code so that we know about the array file

Comment: <ngb-carousel  interval='false' data-interval='false' [pauseOnHover]='true'>
          <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let event of download.downloadImages;" >
            <div class="row" >
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h6 class="help-slideshow-header ">{{event.subTopic}}</h6>
    <div class="text-center slideshow-img-area"><img class="border" class="help-slideshow"  [src]="domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(event.downloadImageSrc)"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
      </ngb-carousel>

Comment: your Array is `downloadImages`... which must be in the TS file

Comment: this.authService.imageDownload(query).subscribe((imageResp) => {
            if (imageResp.status == 2000) {
              let downloadImage = {
                'downloadImageSrc': "data:" + ";base64," + imageResp.data.data,
                'index': i,
                'narration': element.narration,
                'subTopic': subHelpEl.subTopic
              }
              this.download.downloadImages.push(downloadImage);
              i = i + 1;
            }
          });

Comment: inside this authService, look at the URL ad run it in your browser multiple times... maybe the rest API is responding with images in a random order every time which is why you're observing this; to get more help faster, if you can kindly put up a stackblitz which recreates this issue, it'll be easier to help